# How can I save data in Rich Text Editor?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How can i save data in rich text editor into another text item.please help me.i am using jdeveloper 11g.how can i insert save and cancel button in rich text item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which component do you want to show the contents of RichTextEditor?

I am assuming here that you want the content of RichTextEditor component show up in the OutputText which can be done as:

```
<af:richTextEditor id="rte1" label="Enter text" 
                   value="#{viewScope.richValue}" 
                   autoSubmit="true" />
<af:outputText id="ot1" value="${viewScope.richValue}"
               partialTriggers="rte1" />
```

From the above code the data entered in the RichTextEditor component gets stored in the richValue variable which is in the viewScope and  then the OutputText refreshes itself (due to the partial trigger) to display the value.

You cannot insert "Save" and "Cancel" button within the RichTextEditor. But instead you can do something like this:

```
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" layout="vertical">
  <af:richTextEditor id="rte1" label="Enter text" 
                         value="#{viewScope.richValue}" 
                         autoSubmit="true" />
  <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2" layout="horizontal">
    <af:commandButton text="Save" />
    <af:commandButton text="Cancel" />
  </af:panelGroupLayout>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Comment: If your question is answered please choose the appropriate answer and may be an upvote too!

Comment: hi you know how to save the edited text from rich text editor(ex:give color,font change etc) into database and in text field??is it possible to save in database

Comment: Yes it is possible to save in the database. You need to check out how to use JDBC and then use INSERT query directly from your managed bean OR you can use ADF BC to perform the INSERT operation via a ViewObject.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data from one field to by referencing the same memory scoped variable in both cases, like this:

`#{requestScope.value}`

I have no idea what you mean by this:
how can i insert save and cancel button in rich text item

Answer (score 0):

you should use [af:outputFormatted](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_outputFormatted.html) which as the documentation mentions :

> The outputFormatted bean accepts a string in its "value" attribute
>   containing a very limited set of **HTML markup** and **outputs formatted
>   results.**

check the following example :

```
<af:outputFormatted styleUsage="instruction"
                    value="<b>simple outputFormatted</b>"/>
```

Now you take the value from the [RichTextEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_richTextEditor.html) and set it in the OutputFormatted component on your **af:Button** actionListener .

Hope  that Helps .

Comment: This only woks for  a JSP page, for a JSPX page you will get the below error when you include HTML tags like this --> #ViewJobProperties.jsff:1:1: The page failed validation from validator: "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 282; columnNumber: 94; The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "af:outputFormatted" must not contain the '<' character.". Instead, for a JSPX page you should add it this way --> <af:outputFormatted value="&lt;b>This is in bold.&lt;/b> This is not bold"/>